# PHP if value [...] display:none in selectbox

Tags: php, html, mysql

I want to display none if mysql db value **12** [this value not important] on select box and only use PHP and HTML (not javascript etc.)

I use this code for display:none;

```
<div <?php  echo $account->optionselect1; if ($optionselect1 == 12) " style='display: none';"; ?> id="12" type="text" name="12" class="12" >
                         <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="country">Ödeme Günü</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="date" id="date" value="<?php echo @substr($account->date,0,16); ?>" class="form-control input-sm date">
                                </div> <!-- /.form-group -->
                            </div> <!-- /.col-md-4 -->
                            <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-6">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="city">Toplam Tutar</label>
                                    <input type="text" name="city" id="city" placeholder="Tutar" value="<?php echo $account->balance; ?> Türk Lirası" class="form-control" minlength="3" maxlength="20">
                                </div> <!-- /.form-group -->
                            </div> <!-- /.col -->
        </div> <!-- /.selectitem1 -->
```

My select box codes here;

```
<div class="row">
                        <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-12">
                        <div class="form-group">
                <label for="optionselect1">Taksit Yada Tek Ödeme Seçiniz</label>
                <select value="optionselect1" type="text" name="optionselect1" id="optionselect1" class="form-control">
                    <option >Seçin</option>
                    <option type="text" value="12">Tek Ödeme (Taksitsiz)</option>
                    <option type="text" value="13">2 Taksit</option>
                    <option type="text" value="val4">item 4</option>
                </select>
            </div> <!-- /.form-group -->
            </div> <!-- /.col -->
```

My echo codes (for $account->optionselect1) here;

```
@form_validation($insert['optionselect1'], 'optionselect1', 'Option Secin', 'min_length[1]|max_length[20]', __FUNCTION__);
```

**MYSQL database:** dbname>til_accounts>`optionselect1`

**But display:none not working**

I think my echo codes is wrong. What Should I do?

Comment: Try this: `if ($account->optionselect1 == 12) { echo ' style="display: none;"'; }`

Comment: @Chaska What?? Im try this 2 days and you solved this problem 1 min? You are perfect! Thank you. Last question, How can I if optionselect1 == 12 option selected in selectbox?

Comment: Hope this helps: `<option type="text" value="12" <?php if ($optionselect1 == 12) { echo 'selected'; } ?>>Tek Ödeme (Taksitsiz)</option>`

Comment: Yea! it works @Chaska ! Only I change $optionselect1 to $account->optionselect1 and no problem for now. Thank you for everything.

Answer (score 0):

Try this..
   In If condition,I think the data access "if ($optionselect1 == 12)" is Wrong. try with

```
' div if($account->optionselect1 == 12) ?> style='display: none'>'
```